# Getting Memory leaks when using MFC regular DLL with WinUI 3 application

Tags: c++, xaml, dll, mfc, winui-3

Getting memory leaks when using MFC regular DLL with WinUI 3 application.
This leak happens only when I set Page via `window.content()` or `Frame.Navigate()` method and if I don't set page to window content and only activate window, leaks will not come, but in our requirement both showing Page content and use of mfc dll is required.

I reproduce the issue in this sample project [MemoryLeakTestCPP.zip](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/files/10227671/MemoryLeakTestCPP.zip)

This project is tested on Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 ( Version 16.11.8 ) in Debug x86 environment.

here is screenshot of output having leaks.
[memory-leaks screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8l8F.png)

MainPage.xaml is looks like below , if we remove from it then one leak will be reduced, so I think leaks are getting due to no destruction of Page

```
<Page>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button>Click me</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

From MFC DLL, for testing I only declare one object of class(`CTestClass`) from mfc dll in WinUI project.
DLL is linked via .lib in WinUI project.

**Steps to reproduce the bug**

1. Download the project having leaks from [MemoryLeakTestCPP.zip](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/files/10227671/MemoryLeakTestCPP.zip)
2. Unzip and build it in Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 ( Version 16.11.8 ) in Debug x86 environment.
3. Run the application in debug mode
4. Close the application
5. Detected Memory Leaks will be shown in Output tab.

**Expected behavior**

Memory leaks should not be detected

**NuGet packages used in projects are:**

```
Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK.1.2.221116.1
Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools.10.0.22621.755
Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.1.0.211019.2
Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT.2.0.210806.1
```

**Windows version**

Windows 10 (20H2): Build 19042

Comment: Apparently, you're using MFC's memory leak detection infrastructure. While that is a fine tool, when used with C++98/03, it gets easily confused by shared ownership (exercised by COM all along, and formalized with the introduction of [`shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) in C++11). The diagnostic may be just noise, owed to the fact that object life times are no longer strictly scoped. Regardless, you should probably update the C++/WinRT dependency first (by right-clicking the project and selecting *"Manage NuGet Packages..."*) and see if that has any effect.

Comment: (It probably won't have any effect.)

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks, I am not using shared_ptr, also updated the NuGet packages but as you anticipated, it not worked.
WinUI page's destructor and `Unloaded` event is not called.
it will be helpful if you can look at the [MemoryLeakTestCPP.zip](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/files/10227671/MemoryLeakTestCPP.zip) and suggest.

Comment: @IInspectable In addition to my last comment : After using original application(which has same scenario which I reproduce in sample project MemoryLeakTestCPP.zip)  for some time, doing some operation like refresh etc. memory usage is increased as per Task Manager, and at one point Application is crashing